# How can we remove space from bottom of box when we use image with width 100% in it

Tags: html, css

How can we remove space from bottom of box when we use image with width 100% in it

```
<div class="midVideo"><img src="images/videoImg.png" alt="" /></div>

.midVideo{
    width:487px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:solid 12px #630400;
    background:#003;
}

.midVideo img, .midVideo iframe{
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add display block property  to image

Answer (score 3):

```
.midVideo img {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Images are replaced elements. These are treated much alike inline elements - so they are placed onto the [baseline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_%28typography%29) of the parent element. The space below is reserved for letters which excess the height like `pqg` and so on. Since images don't need this space, you just need to define `display:block` on the image to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is

```
<img style="height: 100%;" src="images/videoImg.png" alt="" />
```

Hard way is

```
<div class="midVideo">
<img style="[b]<? $img_size = getimagesize('images/videoImg.png'); if ($img_size[0]>$img_size[1]) echo 'width'; else echo 'height'; ?>[/b]: 100%;" src="images/videoImg.png" />
</div>
```